# Discord.js not sending embed message

Tags: javascript, discord

I'm developing a discord bot with .js and I'm using minecraft-server-util. I believe there are several problems and you may correct me on them, but the main problem is that this code returns no embed or message with the status.

```
client.on('message', msg => {
  const commandName = "javaserverstatus"
  if (msg.content === prefix + commandName) {
    const util = require('minecraft-server-util');
    var serverinfo = null
    util.status('play.hypixel.net') // port is default 25565
     .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        serverinfo = response
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
      const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Bot Command List')
      .setColor(0xff0000)
      .setDescription('IP:' + response.host);
      msg.channel.send(embed);
    });
  }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you just placed your embed in your `error logger` and not in the `.then( ... )` statement. But with the `minecraft-server-until` package, I don't know much about it, so if that wasn't the issue, here is the documentation on the package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/minecraft-server-util

Hope this helps you and have fun developing your Discord API!

```
client.on('message', message => {
  if (message.content === `${prefix}javaserverstatus`) {
    const util = require('minecraft-server-util');
    var serverinfo = null
    util.status('play.hypixel.net') // port is default 25565
     .then((response) => {
        console.log(response);
        serverinfo = response;
    const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
      .setTitle('Bot Command List')
      .setColor(0xff0000)
      .setDescription('IP:' + response.host);
      message.channel.send(embed);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.error(error);
    });
  }
});
```